# GORM: embed a class containing a reference to a domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Given:

- `User`, `File` are domain classes
- src/groovy/Container.groovy:

  ```
  class Container {
    User user
    File file
    Date dateCreated
  }
  ```
- grails-app/domain/WithContainer.groovy:

  ```
  class WithContainer {
    Container c
    String text

    static embedded = ['c']
  }
  ```

I was aiming at mapping WithContainer to a table with the columns:

```
user_id | file_id | date_created | text
```

Is that achievable with GORM?

This setup yields:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: User, at table: with_container, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(c_user)]
```

Thanks

Comment: any reason to have `Container` not among domain classes?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue with a scenario which I believe is more common - i.e. I have an Address class under src/groovy, which consists of 5 common address fields (street1, street2, city, zip, state) and is used as an embedded object in several domain objects (or even twice as billing/shipping address of one object). All address fields were strings, but I'd like to refactor it to actually be an instance of the "State" domain object rather than a "String". I think this is a valid use case and I'm wondering if it's possible or if I need to refactor the objects?

Answer (score 0):

`Container` is not a domain class because it isn't defined under `grails-app/domain/`.

It may be that you are confused about the `embedded` attribute.  Properties in the `embedded` list are persistent properties for which you want all of their attributes stored in the same table as the owning class (`WithContainer` in your case), as opposed to being stored in their own table and referenced with foreign keys.  The property still needs be an instance of a domain class though.

Comment: Thanks. Can the classes be crafted differently, though, to have the above mapping in the DB? My goal is to have multiple domain classes, all sharing a common set of properties that are domain types, while having their respective tables align to the above structure. I guess I'm aiming at a midway between tablePerHierarchy=true (one big table) and tablePerHierarchy=false (multiple tables, but with a reference to a table).